# node.js mysql - Extract datetime in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ format without milliseconds

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm importing datetime information in this format:

```
2020-04-17T19:08:28Z
```

into a mysql datetime column.

When I make a select I get the data in this format back:

```
2020-04-17T19:08:28.000Z
```

What I would like is the original format though. How to do so exactly? So goal:

```
2020-04-17T19:08:28Z
```

That's my setup:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'host',
  user     : 'u',
  password : 'p',
  database : 'db'
});

connection.query("Select * FROM table", function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(rows)
    }
});
```

rows:

```
[ [ {
      column_date: 2020-04-17T19:08:28.000Z,
      ...
    ... 1846 more items ] ]
```

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `DATE_FORMAT()` function for this.
Example:

```
const query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ") formatted_date, * from table";
```

this will format the date as you require.

Also, if you want some more customization, check this: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql/to_char_datetime